# How to initialize qml property list in a loop?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the qml [list](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html) property:

```
Item {
    property list<SomeItem> items: [
        SomeItem { num: 0 },
        SomeItem { num: 1 },
        SomeItem { num: 2 },
        ...
        SomeItem { num: 100 }
    ]
```

Is it possible to initialize it in more clever way? E.g. in some way like the code below?

```
Item {
    property list<SomeItem> items

    ...

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            ??? // items.append( SomeItem {num: i})
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry for the id, I actually want to change my custom property (num) which is used to initialize other properties:

```
SomeItem {
    property int num: 0

    key: getKey(num)
    name: getName(num)

    function getKey(num) {
        return ...
    }

    function getName(num) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 (according to **Mitch** and **ddriver** answers):
I would like to use `Repeater`, however I have to initialize the list property which is provided by some external library.

I've been initializing `SomeItem` with `num` property because the `key` property must be unique and not null. However let's say I can cope with it by setting the `num` in `onCompleted` method:

```
Item {
    property list<SomeItem> items: [
        SomeItem { },
        SomeItem { },
        SomeItem { },
        ...
        SomeItem { }
    ]

    ...

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            items[i].num = i
    }
}
```

So the main problem is that I have to add the `SomeItem {},` line 100 times. Is there any clever way to create such property list dynamically?

Comment: Being honest, the first one is clever to me and the nearest to the underlying paradigm of QML.

Comment: @skypjack - it is absolutely NOT clever, and absolutely redundant.

Comment: Well, if he cares about `id`s, that's the right way indeed. The problem is maybe in the fact that he shouldn't care about them for his case, but from the example I cannot say that.

Comment: @skypjack - no, it is wrong. Both syntactically and conceptually.

Comment: As you prefer, dude. If you have a way to dynamically assign `id`s, please answer the question for I'm curious as well and I'll vote up it for sure.

Comment: The built in `id` is a static construct, it can only be set statically and it can only be referenced statically. The only solution for a dynamic context is to "fake" it by using an associative container, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do makes no sense. And is completely redundant. And impossible.

The `id` property is not a string, nor can it be a number.

In your particular case you want a number id equal to the index of each object in the list, which aside from impossible is also unnecessary. Instead you can access each object easily by using `items[index]`.

If for some reason you really need to assign and use dynamic identifiers, you can use a JS object, which will allow you to do string key lookup rather than integer index:

```
    Item {        
        property var lookup: new Object

        Component {
            id: test

            QtObject {
                property string name
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            lookup["John"] = test.createObject(null, { "name" : "JohnDoe" })
            lookup["Jane"] = test.createObject(null, { "name" : "JaneDoe" })

            console.log(lookup["John"].name) // outputs JohnDoe
            console.log(lookup["Jane"].name) // outputs JaneDoe
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would be valid if and only if `id`s are not a requirement (that is something that makes sense while looking at the problem, of course, but not stated in the question and it could be that the example is a simplified one of a more complex case where `id`s matter). EDIT: question just updated, so this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The [documentation for `list`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html) describes the ways that it can be used:

> A list value can be accessed in a similar way to a JavaScript array:
>
> - Values are assigned using the [] square bracket syntax with comma-separated values
> - The length property provides the number of items in the list
> - Values in the list are accessed using the [index] syntax

You're better off using a [`Repeater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html):

```
Repeater {
    model: 100

    delegate: SomeItem {
        num: index
    }
}
```